# How to write a regular expression formulas to extract words and timestamps in a long string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in a `pandas dataframe` which contains strings in the following format

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Xxxxx Yyy,YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Zzzzz,YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Ttt,YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Xxxx Yyyyyy
```

You can replace the timestamps with any date and time (the timestamps are different) and the words with the alphabet letters (Xxxx, Yyy, etc..) with any words too. Note first that the words always start with a capital letter, second the word part may consist of one or two words (perhaps three too!!), third, not all the strings consist of three segments as above (where segments are separated by commas), it could be one segment, two segments up to four. So for example if it's only one segment the format would be

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Xxxxx Yyyy
```

(notice that there is no comma at the end now)

with 2 segments

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Xxxxxx Yyyy,YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Zzzzz
```

(comma after the first segment but no comma after the second segment)

and so on

Here are some real examples from my data

```
2016-12-18 14:39:45 Charts,2017-01-13 17:09:04 Home,2017-01-13 17:09:45 Converter,2017-01-13 17:09:45 Ria Output

2017-01-10 10:47:36 Home

2017-01-18 07:04:56 Converter,2017-01-18 07:04:56 Ria Output

2017-02-16 17:39:03 Home,2017-02-16 17:39:14 Ria Output,2017-02-16 17:39:51 Converter
```

I want to write a regular expression formulas to extract the timestamps and the words separately in each segment and put each into a new column in the same dataframe. So for the first example from the real data above I want to extract `['Charts', 'Home', 'Converter', 'Ria Output']` for the words and `[2016-12-18 14:39:45 ,2017-01-13 17:09:04 ,2017-01-13 17:09:45 ,2017-01-13 17:09:45]` for the timestamps and put each into a new column (or all words as a list in a column and all timestamps as a list into a separate column all within the same dataframe).

So far I managed to correctly extract the first word(s) in the first segment using

```
df['New_Colmn'] = df['Existing_Colmn'].str.extract(r'\s([A-Za-z\s]+)',expand=True)
```

I'm trying to capture the other word(s) and timestamps in the remaining segments but I didn't succeed. Can you please helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your column looks like this

```
    0
0   2016-12-18 14:39:45 Charts
1   2017-01-13 17:09:04 Home
2   2017-01-13 17:09:45 Converter
3   2017-01-13 17:09:45 Ria Output
```

You can use str.extract to get timestamp and word column like this

```
df[['Timestamp', 'new_column']] =  = df[0].str.extract('(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)', expand = True)
```

You get

```
    0                               Timestamp           new_column
0   2016-12-18 14:39:45 Charts      2016-12-18 14:39:45 Charts
1   2017-01-13 17:09:04 Home        2017-01-13 17:09:04 Home
2   2017-01-13 17:09:45 Converter   2017-01-13 17:09:45 Converter
3   2017-01-13 17:09:45 Ria Output  2017-01-13 17:09:45 Ria Output
```

To drop the first column, you can use

```
df.drop(0, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Hi Vaishali. Thanks for your response. As I mentioned in my post i was able to figure out the first segment (both the timestamp and the words) out of the string. My problem is how to extract the following segments in the same string (the one that comes after the comma)

Answer (score 1):

I just figure it out. As @Vaishali says

```
df[['Timestamp1', 'Page1']] = df['a'].str.extract('(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)',expand=True)

df[['Timestamp2', 'Page2']] = df['a'].str.extract('\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s+[A-Za-z ]+,(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)',expand=True)

df[['Timestamp3', 'Page3']] = df['a'].str.extract('\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s+[A-Za-z ]+,\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s+[A-Za-z ]+,(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)',expand=True)

df[['Timestamp4', 'Page4']] = df['a'].str.extract('\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s+[A-Za-z ]+,\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s+[A-Za-z ]+,\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s+[A-Za-z ]+,(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+)',expand=True)
```